# Array em um mosaico PHP

Tags: php, html, css, array, foreach

Tenho um mosaico montado em html e css, o que preciso é montar um array trazendo as ultimas postagens do banco, e listar nele, percorrendo por todas as divs em sequencia, eu sempre programei um array pra uma DIV só, porem dessa vez é mais de uma div com tamanhos fixos já, nesse caso estou utilizando PHP...

por exemplo o mosaico ficaria mais ou menos assim :

```
<div id="1" width="200"><p>Postagem 1 dia 22/01/2001</p></div>

<div id="2" width="50"><p>Postagem 2 dia 27/02/2001</p></div>

<div id="3" width="100"><p>Postagem 3 dia 30/03/2001</p></div>
```

Comment: Olá @ricksk. Para que comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante fornecer exemplos e deixar claro a dúvida/problema, com trechos de código relevantes.

Comment: Você pode começar fazendo o [tour] pelo site e ler o guia de [ask]. A sua pergunta, da maneira que está não faz muito sentido e é impossível ajudá-lo. Por favor, edite sua pergunta e adicione os códigos que está utilizando e descreva melhor o problema, incluindo, também, a linguagem utilizada nas tags da pergunta.

Comment: Tá muito confuso. Vc quer montar um array em que linguagem?

Comment: é em PHP, desculpe !

Comment: Você precisa mostrar como vem as informações do banco de dados. A pergunta tem que ser o mais clara possível. =) Abraço

Comment: você está usando mysqli ou PDO?